# How to select text at entering to cell

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, grid

I have a `Grid`, and when I'm walking by cells of it, I enter to cell, but whithout selecting text. It's annoying because, when I need to change a value, I need firstly use Backspace key.

What can I do to after entering to cell have selected content of that cell?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of a behavior for this purpose. Below I have included a minimal implementation that provides the functionality I *think* you're looking for:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Behavior{T}"/> of <see cref="TextBox"/> for selecting all text when the text box is focused
/// </summary>
public class TextBoxSelectOnFocusBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (sender as TextBox);

        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.SelectAll();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// React to the behavior being attached to an object
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// React to the behavior being detached from an object
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 But it ought it be mentioned that the `Behavior<T>` is found in the Blend SDK.  Also a templated grid column will be needed, a simple text column will not be able to use the behaviour as it stands.

Comment: Well, I naively saw Grid and imagined a Grid container as opposed to a DataGrid control, but reading again, his mention of cells does seem to suggest the latter. So yes, embedding the text block and attached behavior in a DataGridTemplateColumn would be the way to go.
I would also suggest using WeakReference if this behavior was to be used in a DataGrid as, apparently, OnDetaching isn't always called when it should be.

Comment: Thanks ibebbs for your reply. unfortunately I can't use DataGridTemplateColumn (it's legacy code), so this solution is not for me:/

Comment: What version of Silverlight/DataGridColumn are you using? I was just preparing a spike for using an attached DependencyProperty to achieve the same effect and noticed that *by default* when a DataGridTextColumn enters edit mode, it selects all the text in the cell.So I would guess that you have already templated this column or it is being generated in code. Either way, you should be able to use the approach above.